# Client cannot connect to the server in the container

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, docker-compose, create-react-app

When I run my main Docker Compose, everything builds successfully. However, the client inside the container is unable to make request to the server. This is the input from the browser `(http://server:8080/car/api/user/login net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.)`

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile.server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql-db
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: 12345
    networks:
      - spring-app-mobilele
    
  mysql-db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mobilele
    volumes:
      - mysql-data-mobilele-completed:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - spring-app-mobilele

  client:
    depends_on:
      - server
    build: 
      dockerfile: DockerFile.client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - spring-app-mobilele
    environment:
      REACT_APP_HOST: server
    
volumes:
  mysql-data-mobilele-completed:
networks:
  spring-app-mobilele:
```

As you can see i am mapping the host with the server name in the docker-compose.

When I access the client's shell, I can reach the server using the ping command, confirming that networking is functioning correctly. When I examine the server logs, it appears that the server is not receiving any requests. This suggests that the issue is not on the server side; it does not appear to be related to the Docker Compose file, at least in my assessment. The problem likely lies within the React application. I just don't know what to do. This is my GitHub repo if someone want addition information (https://github.com/SvetlinDimitrov/Car-Web-Application)